# matlab to python lu decomposition different

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm converting some MATLAB code to Python and am observing large numerical discrepancies between the `\` operator and `scipy.linalg.lstsq`, which apparently are interchangeable.

In my code I calculate the `LU` decomposition of some matrix, however Python and Matlab give slightly different answers for 'L'.

Given this input matrix, B:

```
B =  [7.6822         0   -1.0000         0;
     0    0.2896   -1.0000         0;
    -6.4018         0         0   -1.0000;
     0   -0.9350         0   -1.0000]
```

In Python, using `P,L,U = scipy.linalg.lu(B)`:

```
L = [ 1.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          1.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.         -0.30972791  1.          0.        ]
 [-0.83333333 -0.          0.83333333  1.        ]
```

With Matlab `[L,U] = lu(B)`:

```
    L =  1.0000         0         0         0
         0   -0.3097    1.0000         0
        -0.8333         0    0.8333    1.0000
         0    1.0000         0         0
```

In both cases `U` is this:

```
U = [ 7.6822128   0.         -1.          0.        ]
    [ 0.         -0.93502772  0.         -1.        ]
    [ 0.          0.         -1.         -0.30972791]
    [ 0.          0.          0.         -0.74189341]
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code and the result that you expect to get? I receive no such discrepancies when I test under MATLAB and Numpy 1.9.

Comment: added example outputs. my actual code is a bit more involved than U\L, but debugging I found even this result was way off.

Comment: You might want to double check your MATLAB code. I just ran `U\L` with the example matrices you gave and got exactly what you have from Python.

Comment: hmm, all i run is `[L,U] = lu(AA(:,:,k))` then `U\L`, U and L are both the same as Python, but the result is not.

Comment: @eigenchris theres isn't anything I have to do with the result of U\L to make it match python, i just get the solution right?

Comment: @chris All I can tell you is that I copy/pasted the `U` and `L` matrices directly from your post (inserting `;` instead of `] [` to make new rows) and ran `U\L`. If you are still having trouble, can you put the complete exact MATLAB code you are using in your post so we can run it too?

Comment: I just did that and I get the same answer.  it turns out the the problem is the `lu`, its rows are a bit different...ill update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out...in MATLAB, `[L,U] = lu(A)` returns `L` already premultiplied by permutation matrix `P`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that scipy.linalg.lu() has the optional parameter permute_l set to False.  You can either set it to True, e.g. 
`(L,U) = scipy.linalg.lu(A,permute_l=True)`

or alternatively performing the permutation yourself afterwards, e.g.,

`(P,L,U) = scipy.linalg.lu(A)
 L = P@L`